# React use parameters in jsx variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to react and I'm trying to substitute a part of a jsx return I'm repeating in a react component, but there are slight differences in each repetition so I want to pass a simple boolean as a parameter to the variable so I can check those inside jsx. Here is what I've done so far:

```
function links(condition){
   console.log("Condition is: " + condition);
   return(<h1 className={`mr-10  ${ condition === true ? 'flex' : 'hidden' }`>Test</h1>);
}

const Navbar = () => { 
   return( <nav>
       <div> {links.call(false)} </div> 
       <div> {links.call(true)} </div>
   </nav> 
); }
```

This returns `Condition is:`  then `Condition is: Undefined` in the console. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to actually look up what `.call` does? Also, if you want to split code in that way, in my opinion you should almost always make `links` a component.

Comment: Why not directly calling links like: links(false) and links(true) in the JSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down there you can see the "proper" way of using react:

```
function Links({ condition }) {
  return(
    <h1 className={`mr-10  ${ condition === true ? 'flex' : 'hidden' }`>
      Test
    </h1>
  );
}

const Navbar = () => { 
  return(
    <nav>
      <div>
        <Links condition={false} />
      </div> 
      <div>
        <Links condition={true} />
      </div> 
    </nav> 
  );
}
```

Note:

- Better call you component with a caps: `link` => `Link`
- To call a component use `<Component {...props} />`
- The props (parameters) are passed as a object in the first parameter of the function

Comment: I see, so I have to create a component for it, right? This indeed worked. Thanks, guess I wasn't thinking the "react" way.

Comment: Yep, if you want to reuse the logic, you create a separated component and pass him down props and logic.